# xdotool export bad variable name

Tags: xdotool

I have a probably very simple problem, but it's taking a lot of time and I can't seem to find a good solution.

I'm using fusuma on my laptop to use gestures on my touchpad and for that I want xdotool to execute some keypresses.

When I execute this alone in a terminal, it works as expected:

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
```

But in my fusuma config file the following code doesn't work, while it did on my previous laptop

```
command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right'
```

It then says:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

So I found that I should use this:

```
  command: 'export DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left'
```

But then it says this:

```
sh: 1: export: ctrl+alt+Left: bad variable name
```

Does someone see what goes wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Jack

Answer (score 1):

OK,
Turns out a simple restart fixed the original command in the fusuma config.yml

```
command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right'
```

Comment: I cannot accept this answer yet FYI